# React dropzone uploader extra.reject, dropzoneReject not working for custom extension other than MIME types in accept

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropzone.js, dropzone, react-dropzone

I have been using react-dropzone-uploader I am passing accept prop as below

```
accept=".glb"
```

for this extension, extra.reject in "inputContent" function always returns false when dropping other format files.
but when I pass the proper MIME types like below

```
accept="image/*,audio/*,video/*"
```

it is returning extra.reject as true when dropping other format files.

just wondering if there is any workaround to trigger "extra.reject" to be true when other format files are dropped when I give the custom extension.